# How to get the dimensions of the visible part of the JScrollPane-based window

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, viewport, jsplitpane

This `JScrollPane` based window is a top part of the `JSplitPane`.

`getBounds()`, `getWidth()`, `getHeight()` all return the full size of the window, including the invisible (scrollable) part.

I want to know the dimensions of the visible part only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an example which print the height and width of the *visible part only* ,

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class TestWidth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextPane newsTextPane = new JTextPane();
        newsTextPane.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(newsTextPane);

        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setSize(300, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Height : " + scrollPane.getViewport().getSize().height + "\nWidth :" + scrollPane.getViewport().getSize().width);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you have look at [JViewport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html), you can derive  [JViewpor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#operation)t from [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change this class' code, I can only work with it.

Comment: you can't to need any class' code, you needed only to extract JViewport and work with it

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for [JComponent#getVisibleRect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getVisibleRect%28%29).

> Returns the `Component`'s "visible rectangle" - the intersection of this component's visible rectangle, `new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight())`, and all of its ancestors' visible rectangles.